# error while changing table engine to InnoDB

Tags: mysql

I am changing table engine from MyISAM to InnoDB:

```
use db;
alter table table engine=innodb;
```

But, I've faced a very strange problem.

I can change engine of all tables, but except certain tables,
whose names end with `_1`.

For example, I can change tables `test_2`, `test_xy`, but I can't change a table `test_1`. When I try to do it the following error occurs:

```
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'db.#sql-3d9_348' (errno: 139)
```

The above is not only one. I have `learning_1`, `learning_2`, `learning_xy` and so many pairs like that.

I don't know why this happens. Because `_1` is not a special strings such as backtick, quotes, dollar sign, number sign or something. And I don't think it is related with a length of db, table name. Also, not related with table size.

Is there a know bug or issue in altering table engine with a certain table name?

Comment: whats the engine type for the tables ending with _1 ?

Comment: alll tables were MyISAM. regardless of `_1`, `_2` and `_xy`

Comment: What version of MySQl are you using ? Fyi.. FULLTEXT index support for InnoDB tables requires >= MySQL 5.6.4

Though not sure if you got type FULLTEXT in tables with _1 ?

Comment: 5.5. But, no tables are using text-based field. only integer, tinyint and decimals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's my fault.

It is not related with `_1`, but it is related with the number of columns.

Tables with `_1` at the end of the name have 1,001 columns.

It is too big for [InnoDB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-restrictions.html)

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why `_1` is an issue, but maybe this is a workaround

```
use db;
RENAME TABLE test_1 TO test1;
alter table test1 engine=innodb;
RENAME TABLE test1 TO test_1;
```

Of course I would suggest a backup before doing anything